# How to install LibreOffice 5.0 in Ubuntu?

Tags: libreoffice

Libreoffice 5.0 was just released.

tried

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:libreoffice/libreoffice-5.0
```

But

> cannot add PPA: 'ppa:~libreoffice/ubuntu/libreoffice-5-0'.
>   The team named '~libreoffice' has no PPA named 'ubuntu/libreoffice-5-0'

**Edit: You can add Libreofiice 5.0 using**

> sudo add-apt-repository -y ppa:libreoffice/ppa

Comment: Where did you get the PPA, link please

Comment: I'm going to close this Q with our "standard libreoffice latest version" Q&A -

Comment: @dhiya - yes it does - have a look at the PPA in question - it holds LO 5 packages and the upgrade process as described in the answer will install that over your existing LO installation.

Comment: If you solved your problem yourself, please [answer your own question](/help/self-answer) and accept it. Don't put the answer in your question!

Comment: @David Foerster Please explain how to answer this question as it is already marked as duplicate?

Comment: Sorry for the canned and unfitting comment. It only applies, if your question isn't closed. If you believe, that your question is no duplicate, please explain how it differs substantially from the linked question and [request to have it reopened](/help/reopen-questions). You can and (in most cases) should add that explanation to your question. Bear in mind, that your proposed solution is exactly the same as the top answer of the linked question.

Comment: http://www.webupd8.org/2015/08/install-libreoffice-50-in-ubuntu-or.html

Comment: dup of another question with 35+ votes

Answer (score 42, accepted):

Simply use the official PPA :

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:libreoffice/ppa
sudo apt-get update
```

---

**Option 1 :** You don't have `libreoffice` yet :

Open a terminal (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd>) and run:

```
sudo apt-get install libreoffice
```

Or install using Ubuntu Software center :

[image: Install via the software center]

---

**Option 2 :** You already have an old version of LibreOffice (4.x) :

Open a terminal (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd>) and run:

```
sudo apt-get upgrade
```

Comment: It's better to use [LibreOffce Fresh PPA](https://launchpad.net/~libreoffice/+archive/ubuntu/ppa/), just add it to your system and run **Software Updater ** to upgrade your system. via: http://ubuntuhandbook.org/index.php/2015/08/upgrade-libreoffice-5-0-ubuntu-linux-mint/

Comment: Why is the 5.0 PPA down?

Comment: The correct link seems to be https://launchpad.net/~libreoffice/+archive/ubuntu/libreoffice-5-0

Answer (score 3):

If you are looking for RC5, you can try

[Libreoffice Packaging Team](https://launchpad.net/~libreoffice/+archive/ubuntu/ppa)

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:libreoffice/ppa
```

Or

[Libreoffice Pre-Release](https://launchpad.net/~libreoffice/+archive/ubuntu/libreoffice-prereleases)

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:libreoffice/libreoffice-prereleases
```

Keep in mind they are early releases and unstables versions.