# PDF editor suggestions

Tags: master-pdf-editor

I have some templates that I need to change the font size on. Any suggestions as to the best free software to do this, and can you tell me how to change the font size? Thanks.

Comment: What about the soft in your tag?

Comment: Master pdf is the best https://code-industry.net/get-masterpdfeditor/

Comment: @Pilot6 since version 5 not as free as it used to be. Adds s watermark to edited files.

Comment: [alternativeto.net {Linux master-pdf alternatives}](https://alternativeto.net/software/master-pdf-editor/?platform=linux) is my go to for finding alternatives.

Answer (score 0):

> LibreOffice Draw

most of the distributions now come with LibreOffice 
if you haven't, follow this link:
[How to install LibreOffice 5.0 in Ubuntu?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/656794/how-to-install-libreoffice-5-0-in-ubuntu)

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned above LibreOffice is a good sw for this issue.

I prefer [MasterPDF](https://code-industry.net/free-pdf-editor/?-update&x&ver=4389), which is a commercial sw, but for my issues it is perfect. 
You could also use pdftk, uncompress the document and edit and modify it from commandline with sed.